# How do I reconnect to Cassandra using Hector?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have the following code:

```
StringSerializer ss = StringSerializer.get();
String cf = "TEST";
CassandraHostConfigurator conf = new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160");
conf.setCassandraThriftSocketTimeout(40000);
conf.setExhaustedPolicy(ExhaustedPolicy.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK);
conf.setRetryDownedHostsDelayInSeconds(5);
conf.setRetryDownedHostsQueueSize(128);
conf.setRetryDownedHosts(true);
conf.setLoadBalancingPolicy(new LeastActiveBalancingPolicy());
String key = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", conf);
Keyspace keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("TestCluster", cluster);
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, StringSerializer.get());    int count = 0;
while (!"q".equals(new Scanner( System.in).next())) {
    try{
        mutator.insert(key, cf, HFactory.createColumn("column_" + count, "v_" + count, ss, ss));
    count++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I can write some values using it, but when I restart cassandra, it fails. Here is the log:

> [15:11:07]  INFO [CassandraHostRetryService ] Downed Host Retry service started with >queue size 128 and retry delay 5s
>   [15:11:07]  INFO [JmxMonitor                ] Registering JMX >me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_ASG:ServiceType=hector,MonitorType=hector
>   [15:11:17] ERROR [HThriftClient             ] Could not flush transport (to be expected >if the pool is shutting down) in close for client: CassandraClient
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>     at >org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:147)
>     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.flush(TFramedTransport.java:156)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.client.HThriftClient.close(HThriftClient.java:98)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.client.HThriftClient.close(HThriftClient.java:26)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.closeClient(HConnectionManager.java:308)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:257)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97)
>     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
>     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.insert(MutatorImpl.java:69)
>     at com.app.App.main(App.java:40)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
>     at >org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:145)
>     ... 9 more
>   [15:11:17] ERROR [HConnectionManager        ] MARK HOST AS DOWN TRIGGERED for host >localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
>   [15:11:17] ERROR [HConnectionManager        ] Pool state on shutdown: >:{localhost(127.0.0.1):9160}; IsActive?: true; Active: 1; Blocked: 0; Idle: 15; NumBeforeExhausted: 49
>   [15:11:17]  INFO [ConcurrentHClientPool     ] Shutdown triggered on :{localhost(127.0.0.1):9160}
>   [15:11:17]  INFO [ConcurrentHClientPool     ] Shutdown complete on :{localhost(127.0.0.1):9160}
>   [15:11:17]  INFO [CassandraHostRetryService ] Host detected as down was added to retry queue: localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
>   [15:11:17]  WARN [HConnectionManager        ] Could not fullfill request on this host CassandraClient
>   [15:11:17]  WARN [HConnectionManager        ] Exception: 
>   me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorTransportException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.client.HThriftClient.getCassandra(HThriftClient.java:82)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:236)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97)
>     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
>     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.insert(MutatorImpl.java:69)
>     at com.app.App.main(App.java:40)
>   Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:147)
>     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.flush(TFramedTransport.java:157)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.send_set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:466)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:455)
>     at >me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.client.HThriftClient.getCassandra(HThriftClient.java:78)
>     ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
>     at >org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:145)
>     ... 9 more
>   [15:11:17]  INFO [HConnectionManager        ] Client CassandraClient released to inactive or dead pool. Closing.
>   [15:11:17]  INFO [HConnectionManager        ] Client CassandraClient released to inactive or dead pool. Closing.
>   [15:11:17]  INFO [HConnectionManager        ] Added host localhost(127.0.0.1):9160 to pool

Comment: My thrift_max_message_length_in_mb = 16, cassandra 1.0.7, hector 1.0-2 and  I have waited  more and less than 5 seconds, but it still does not work.

Comment: The problem was in hector's version. With 1.0-5 it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set -

```
conf.setRetryDownedHostsDelayInSeconds(5);
```

Try to to wait after the restart for more than 5 seconds.
Also, you may need to upgrade.

What is the size **thrift_max_message_length_in_mb** you have set?

Kind regards.